# Categorize DynamoDB fetched table data for collection view cells

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, nosql

I am working on a services app in which user creates a post whose details are saved in a dynamoDb table. I have fetched all the data in the table and now i want to display the data in collection view controller such that each cell represents single post. Now i am not sure how to segregate every single post from that data and provide it to collection view. My table fields are: 
[Table_Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BNkS.png)

My code is:

```
import UIKit
import AWSDynamoDB

class ProvidingViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var PCV: UICollectionView!
    let db = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()
    let scanExpression = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
    var counter:Int = 0

     var imagex = ["UserIcon.png", "chat2.png","UserIcon.png", "delete.png","UserIcon.png", "delete.png","UserIcon.png", "delete.png","UserIcon.png", "delete.png","UserIcon.png", "delete.png"]

    var images:[String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scanner()

    }
    ///
    func scanner(){

        scanExpression.limit = 2000

        db.scan(PostDetails.self, expression: scanExpression).continueWith(block: { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in

            if task.result != nil {
                let paginatedOutput = task.result!

                //use the results
                for item in paginatedOutput.items as! [PostDetails] {
                     self.counter = paginatedOutput.items.count
                      self.images.append(item.userId!)


                }

                if ((task.error) != nil) {
                    print("Error: Could not fetch PostDetails table data")
                }
                return nil

            }

            return nil
        })

    }

    ///

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = PCV.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "c", for: indexPath) as! CellsCollectionViewCell
        cell.ProvImage.image = UIImage(named: imagex[indexPath.row])
        cell.ProvLabel.text = images[indexPath.row]
        return cell


    }


}
```

I have images array in which i am fetching data. When i print out the array it has data but when i assign it to collection view controller, screen is displayed empty i.e no cells. Please help. Thanks

Comment: I think you need to convert the data into image first, can you show what you are seeing when you print the array.

Comment: I have another table with images data and links. That's not the issue. Images is an array just to test. Once i append userID to images array then print it, it shows all the userIds in the table. The issue is that i want to get the data separated row by row so that i can then use that as single post data and display on collection view cell.

Comment: ok than do this: add breakpoint in cellforItemAt, and than see whether the cell is being generated or not.

Comment: I am inserting data in array as i get it but no cell is generated and array.count returns zero which means cellForItem.. loads when view loads and at that time there is no data in array. so blank collection view again. What it requires that array should be ready before you land at collection view and only then it generates cell. This view controller is home screen and  don't know where should i get the data before landing at the main screen so that array is not empty.

Comment: can you tell me in which method you are loading data into array? or share that code?

Comment: it's AWS scan method to get data from table. It's all set and working. Only issue is that collection view loads even before this code is run and arrays are filled. Code is: [CodeLink](https://codeshare.io/G8Jg64)

Comment: I know i got your issue, just follow my answer it will work. give it a try.

Comment: also remove PCV.reloadData() from viewdidload.

Comment: thanks,  i have removed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real issue you are facing is that when View loads the images array is empty and `CollectionView` loads empty and when you are loading images in the array in the scanner method you are not calling `reloadData` for `CollectionView` that is why you are not able to see anything in the `CollectionView` after data is being loaded into your array. I am updating your scanner method , try this and it will work.

```
func scanner(){

    scanExpression.limit = 2000

    db.scan(PostDetails.self, expression: scanExpression).continueWith(block: { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in

        if task.result != nil {
            let paginatedOutput = task.result!

            //use the results
            for item in paginatedOutput.items as! [PostDetails] {
                 self.counter = paginatedOutput.items.count
                  self.images.append(item.userId!)


            }
            //This line is important because it tells collectionview that i have new data so please refresh.
            PCV.reloadData()
            if ((task.error) != nil) {
                print("Error: Could not fetch PostDetails table data")
            }
            return nil

        }

        return nil
    })

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shabir, let me try this.

Comment: Thanks @Shabir, you are great. It's been my headache for two days but you finally solved the problem. I am now working on it and i will comment if i face further issues. Thanks.

Comment: welcome and BTW you can upvote my answer as well for others :)

Comment: I have upvoted and it's recorded but does not show up as my reputation score is <15.